# locking down apache server

Tags: apache-2.2

i have an apache server running several vhosts.  all of my vhosts are working great, but i came across a security hole that i need to plug.

if i go a dns entry, i get the appropriate vhost, if i go to the IP address of the server, i get the first web site that happened to be deployed.  how do i lock that down so if you go to the IP address you get an error or something?

thank you.

Comment: This may not be nice, but why do you call this a security hole?

Comment: the simplest reason is if you hit it by IP address, the server does something that it isn't supposed to do.  This type of issue i call a security hole.  I don't know if its industry standard terminology, but its how i approach the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just create a blank vhost and make sure it is the first vhost added to apache.. being the top of the file of the first file in alphabetic order.

What I do is this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/localhost

    ErrorLog logs/localhost-error_log
    CustomLog logs/localhost-access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

So put that at the top of your list or I have all my vhosts broken out into an include directory so my filename is

```
00-localhost.conf
```

In /var/www/localhost you can have like a empty index.html or whatever you want and all requests to the IP or hosts that are directed towards you but aren't listed in a vhost will go there.

Comment: You could even use `mod_redirect` to have that vhost redirect to your company site on another server entirely, rather than serving an error.